# Proof of inequality solution

Tags: proof-verification, inequality

I have to solve this inequality:

$$5 ≤ 4|x − 1| + |2 − 3x|$$

and prove its solution with one (or 2 or 3) of this sentences:

$$∀x∀y |xy| = |x||y|$$

$$∀x∀y(y ≤ |x| ↔ y ≤ x ∨ y ≤ −x)$$

$$∀x∀y(|x| ≤ y ↔ x ≤ y ∧ −x ≤ y)$$

The solution of inequality is:

$$(-\infty, \frac{1}{7}> U <\frac{11}{7}, \infty)$$

But I have a hard time with proving the solution with the sentence. E.g. if I choose the second one I get this:

5 ≤ 4(x-1) + (2-3x) ∨ 5 ≤ - [4(x-1) + (2-3x)] <=>

5 ≤ 4x - 4 + 2 - 3x ∨ 5 ≤ -(4x-4+2-3x) <=>

5 ≤ x-2 ∨ 5 ≤ -x + 2 <=> 7 ≤ x ∨ x ≤ 3

and that is wrong.

Can someone help me out, please? Sorry for bad English, that is not my first language.

EDIT:
Sentences should be applicable. I have another inequality which is already solved and it was done like this:

|3x| ≤ |2x − 1|

(x ∈ R | −1 ≤ x ≤1/5)

Sentences:

∀x∀y(y ≤ |x| ↔ y ≤ x ∨ y ≤ −x)  (1)

∀x∀y(|x| ≤ y ↔ x ≤ y ∧ −x ≤ y)   (2)

Solution:
We make another sentence which we have to prove:

∀x( |3x| ≤ |2x − 1| ↔ −1 ≤ x ≤ 1/5)  (3)

|3x| ≤ |2x − 1| ⇔ |3x| ≤ 2x − 1 ∨ |3x| ≤ −(2x − 1) ⇔

3x ≤ 2x − 1 ∧ −3x ≤ 2x − 1 ∨ 3x ≤ −(2x − 1) ∧ −3x ≤ −(2x − 1) ⇔

x ≤ −1 ∧ 1 ≤ 5x ∨ 5x ≤ 1 ∧ −1 ≤ x ⇔

1/5 ≤ x ≤ −1 ∨ −1 ≤ x ≤1/5⇔ −1 ≤ x ≤1/5

So we proved sentence (3)

Comment: Not sure if you can apply your sentences there, besides, why would one make you even try do that ... there is a standard way to solve this type of problems: divide your domain into regions, where the signs of each expression under the absolute operator is same for the entire region, and then simply get rid of the absolute operator.

Comment: also, get some graph paper (quadrille paper) and simply graph $y = 4|x-1| +|2-3x|$ for, say $0 \leq x \leq 2.$ Enough to divide each unit on the $x$ axis into six parts, so that one square means $1/6.$ I drew the thing yesterday, not hard.

Answer (score 1):

The sentences (rules) you stated will not be sufficient (applicable), because the given inequality is not a single absolute value, but a sum of two.

The standard **algebraic** method to solve the absolute value inequality is to divide into intervals:
$$5 ≤ 4|x − 1| + |2 − 3x| \Rightarrow \\
\begin{align} 
1) \ &\begin{cases}x\le \frac23\\ 5\le -4(x-1)+(2-3x) \end{cases} \Rightarrow  \ \ \begin{cases}x\le \frac23\\ x\le \frac1{7}\end{cases} \Rightarrow x\in (-\infty,\frac17] \ \ \text{or} \\
2) \ &\begin{cases}\frac23< x<1 \\ 5\le -4(x-1)-(2-3x) \end{cases}\ \Rightarrow  \ \ \begin{cases}\frac23< x<1\\ x\le -3\end{cases} \Rightarrow x\in \emptyset\ \ \ \text{or} \\
3) \ &\begin{cases}1\le x \\ 5\le 4(x-1)-(2-3x) \end{cases} \Rightarrow  \ \ \begin{cases}1\le x\\ x\ge \frac{11}7\end{cases} \Rightarrow x\in [\frac{11}7,+\infty)\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \end{align}$$
Hence, the final solution is: $$x\in (-\infty,\frac17]\cup [\frac{11}7,+\infty).$$

==============================================================

Let's try:
$$5 ≤ 4|x − 1| + |2 − 3x| \iff \\
4|x-1|\ge 5-|2-3x| \iff \\
\big[4(x-1)\ge 5-|2-3x| \big] \ \ \lor \ \ \big[-4(x-1)\ge 5-|2-3x|\big] \iff \\
\big[|2-3x|\ge 9-4x \big] \ \ \lor \ \ \big[|2-3x|\ge 1+4x\big] \iff \\
\big[2-3x\ge 9-4x \lor -(2-3x)\ge 9-4x\big] \lor \big[2-3x\ge 1+4x \lor -(2-3x)\ge 1+4x\big] \iff \\
\big[x\ge 7 \lor x\ge \frac{11}7\big] \lor \big[x\le \frac17 \lor x\le -3\big] \iff \\
\big[x\ge \frac{11}7\big] \lor \big[x\le \frac17\big] \iff \\
x\in (-\infty,\frac17]\cup [\frac{11}7,+\infty)$$

Answer (score 0):

Part (I) fill in this table
$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
x & x-1&|x-1|&4|x-1| &-3x&2-3x&|2-3x|& y = 4|x-1| +|2-3x| \\ \hline
\frac{-1}{6} & &&&&&&  \\  \hline
0 &  &&&&&& \\ \hline
\frac{1}{6}  &&&&&& & \\  \hline
\frac{1}{3} & &&&&&&  \\ \hline
\frac{1}{2} & &&&&&&  \\ \hline
\frac{2}{3} & &&&&&&  \\ \hline
\frac{5}{6} & &&&&&&  \\ \hline
1 & &&&&&&  \\ \hline
\frac{7}{6}  &&&&&& & \\ \hline
\frac{4}{3} &  &&&&&& \\ \hline
\frac{3}{2} & &&&&&&  \\ \hline
\frac{5}{3} & &&&&&&  \\ \hline
\frac{11}{6} & &&&&&&  \\ \hline
2 & &&&&&&  \\ \hline
\end{array}
$$

Part (II)
draw on graph paper, horizontal axis called $x,$ vertical axis called $y$